# how can set a div center of other div with CSS?

Tags: html, css, center

for example i designed a div for border style and i designed another div to center of that , how can i set it to center of larger div?

```css
.Profile_Photo_Border {
     border: 3px solid #052d31;
     height: 90px;
     width: 90px;
     border-radius: 3px;
    }
    .Profile_Photo {
     background-color:#005e67;
     height: 80px;
     width: 80px;
     border-radius: 3px;
     alignment-adjust:middle;
     text-align:center;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="Profile_Photo_Border">
      <div class="Profile_Photo"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following style `display: flex;` to the `parent div` and

```
margin: 0 auto;
align-self: center;
```

to the child div to align it center horizontally as well as vertically.

So the styles become:

```
.Profile_Photo_Border {

    border: 3px solid #052d31;
    height: 90px;
    width: 90px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: flex;
}
.Profile_Photo {
    background-color:#005e67;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    alignment-adjust:middle;
    text-align:center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    align-self: center;
}
```

See the fiddle: "https://jsfiddle.net/ukgnnp4k/"

See the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: GLad to help you @MojtabaSh :)

Comment: You should note that this is using flexbox and is not compatible with Internet Explorer 8 or 9 and possibly not 10. [(source)](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) If you need to support those browsers, it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your CSS to:

```
.Profile_Photo_Border {
  border: 3px solid #052d31;
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: relative;
}

.Profile_Photo {
  background-color: #005e67;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align:center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -40px;
  margin-top: -40px;
}
```

This link also might be helpful:
https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: thanks for your answer, is there any way other for make div center of larger div without use the width and height. for example you had use half of height for margin-top , is there anyway others for don't use height?

Comment: Do you mean in the case that you don't specify a height and width for the (smaller) child element?

Answer (score 1):

Your second div has 10px size lesser than the first one in height and width.
So to centralize the middle one add margin:5px;to the second div, Profile_Photo.

Comment: Obviously a simple solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
.Profile_Photo {

    background-color:#005e67;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 5px auto;

}
```

Comment: using 5px gives you the top and down margin. and using the auto, automatically sets the div to the center of the parent div by stting the left and right margin.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this css.

```
.Profile_Photo_Border {
        border: 3px solid #052d31;
        height: 90px;
        width: 90px;
        border-radius: 3px;
    }
    .Profile_Photo {
        background-color:#005e67;
        height: 80%;
        width: 80%;
        border-radius: 3px;
        text-align:center;
        margin:10px auto;
    }
```

Use this http://jsfiddle.net/18yao91v/244/

Answer (score 0):

If the outer div and inner div has fixed width, then you can use [css `position`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) to align inner element.

See below CSS.

```css
.Profile_Photo_Border {
     border: 3px solid #052d31;
     height: 90px;
     width: 90px;
     border-radius: 3px;
        position: relative;
    }
    .Profile_Photo {
     background-color:#005e67;
     height: 80px;
     width: 80px;
     border-radius: 3px;
  /*   alignment-adjust:middle;  No need to use this. */
     text-align:center;
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        left: 5px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="Profile_Photo_Border">
      <div class="Profile_Photo"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way of centering the div inside a div irrespective of width and height - [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJBLvV)

```
.Profile_Photo_Border {
    border: 3px solid #052d31;
    height: 90px;
    width: 90px;
    border-radius: 3px;
  position: relative;
}
.Profile_Photo {
    background-color:#005e67;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

And a [guide](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/) from CSS Tricks for centering the `div`.

Another [guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) from CSS Tricks on Flexbox which is another better way.

Hope this might help you understand better.

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your answer, don't just link to a CodePen. For why, see [this Meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers), and the [good answer FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here are my 2 cents, I used the display:table.cell css style:

```css
 .Profile_Photo_Border {
  border: 3px solid #052d31;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: table-cell; /*added*/
  vertical-align: middle; /*added*/
}

.Profile_Photo {
  background-color: #005e67;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center; /*added*/
  margin: auto; /*added*/
}
```